# Oxidshop - Override changebasket function in BasketComponent

Tags: php, oxid

I am customising Oxidshop for one of my clients. I want to customise the "changebasket" function in BasketComponent file to add more validations to it. 
For this purpose I have also created a custom module. I am trying to extend the class using metadata file.

```
'extend' => array(
        'oxcmp_basket' => \MyVendor\Basket\Application\Components\BasketComponent::class,
    ),
```

The BasketComponent file has following code,

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Basket\Application\Components;

/**
 * Class LinslinSliderMain.
*/
class BasketComponent extends BasketComponent_parent
{
 /**
 * @param null $sProductId
 * @param null $dAmount
 * @param null $aSel
 * @param null $aPersParam
 * @param bool $blOverride
 */
 public function changebasket($sProductId = null, $dAmount = null, $aSel = null, $aPersParam = null, $blOverride = true)
 {
    echo 'call success';exit;
    parent::changebasket($sProductId, $dAmount, $aSel, $aPersParam, $blOverride);
 }
}
```

The gets activated. However, when I refresh any page in frontend, it gets deactivated automatically. I don't know, what's wrong with the code.

**EDIT**: I am getting this error in oxideshop.log file

```
Module class MyVendor\Basket\Application\Components\BauerBasketComponent not found. Module ID basket disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your OXID eShop version it might be a different line, but the error message you are stating originates from [`OxidEsales\EshopCommunity\Core\Module\ModuleChainsGenerator::onModuleExtensionCreationError`](https://github.com/OXID-eSales/oxideshop_ce/blob/master/source/Core/Module/ModuleChainsGenerator.php#L411).

When activating your module, the system tries to generate the class chain with your `BasketComponent` class in it. As your class is a namespaced class, OXID tries to check if it can find the [class via the composer autoload file](https://github.com/OXID-eSales/oxideshop_ce/blob/master/source/Core/Module/ModuleChainsGenerator.php#L242), if not, the shop throws this exception.

So I assume the module is not installed via composer, at least the namespace seems unknown to composer. You can check in the [module documentation](https://docs.oxid-esales.com/developer/en/6.0/modules/skeleton/composerjson/module_via_composer.html#autoload) on how this should be achieved

Hope I could help

/Flo